# How translate english word in hindi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I change English Word in hindi in Asp.net Mvc 4 without using any translatore or google API. Suppose a user enters his name in textbox in english, it should automatically get converted in hindi as types. just like happend  Google Translator

Example  :-

Mohit ----- मोहित

Comment: Do you mean translate, or [transliterate](http://utilities.webdunia.com/hindi/transliteration.html)?

Comment: If user write mohit by keyboard it autometicaly convert in hindi in any textbox where user want to write. For example if user write Mohit in texbox it auotmeticaly change in मोहित....

Answer (score -1):

Your problem can be solved with a parser. Have a look at compiler making. The parser is an important part of it.

Anyhow you need a state machine which represents the rules for the transliteration. I don't know how complicated it will be to make one for Hindi->English or where you can find one. If you have the state machine it is quite easy to implement it.